# Delphi и WPE PRO, как помешать перехвату пакетов?

Tags: пакет, delphi, сокеты

Доброго дня. Друг держит сервер одной онлайн рпг-шки. Ушлый народ научился валить сервер посылкой заведомо неверных пакетов при помощи программы WPE PRO (такой редактор пакетов, записывает и умеет изменять и пересылать). Так вот, моя задача - написать клиентское приложение и как-то помешать этим ушлым игрокам пользоваться данной софтиной.

Какой помощи хочу от вас, уважаемые профессионалы - это всего лишь подсказки, куда рыть и копать? Лично у меня идей нет, к сожалению. Искать в процессах и убивать можно, но тут несколько критических моментов имеется. Первое, у программы должны быть права. Потом, процесс-таки можно скрыть каким-нибудь HideToolz, но и это можно обойти и найти-таки софтину. Но главная проблема в том, что достаточно послать **один** пакет - и сервер лежит. Как сделал я сейчас - моя программа общается с сервером через TCP-сокет раз в 10 секунд на тарабарском, и если  у человека программа не запущена, админ видит это и может выкинуть человека из игры, но всё дело в том, что сервер ляжет в любом случае, хоть человек в игре, хоть нет - отсылается неверный пакет авторизации и сервер ложится баиньки. Думал в сторону перехвата функций типа Recv, Send, но как-то не радует меня такая перспектива, ни разу не занимался перехватами, я не профи и не осилю грамотный перехват. Да и не стоит лезть глубоко в систему, имхо.

В общем, подайте идеи, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю за вашу ценную помощь.

P.S. Пишу в RAD XE5, сервер на centos, серверная часть программы работает под wine =)

Comment: серверное приложение Ваше или нет? Если Ваше, можете ли Вы его изменять?

Wine на сервере с делфи -  это жестоко.

Comment: Серверное приложение? Если то, что движет игру, то нет, не моё. Исходников нет, менять не могу (тогда бы вообще проблем не было). А жестокое приложение под вайном - это мои изыски =) Его пока в расчёт не берём. Надо как-то на стороне клиента помешать запуску/эксплуатации WPE. Ну, это как я понимаю.

Comment: Если сервер поправить нельзя, то может лучше серверную часть под свою прокси, фильтрующую гадкие пакеты поместить?

Ну, прокси писать придется, но IMHO это более достойное занятие, чем убивать процессы на клиенте и бороться с софтоломателями на их площадке.

Comment: "может лучше серверную часть под свою прокси, фильтрующую гадкие пакеты поместить?"

А можно подробнее? Как примерно можно реализовать это?

Comment: Комментирование странное. Пишу снова. Можно было бы убивать пакеты на сервере, если бы не шифрование между клиентом игры и сервером, а чтобы вскрыть, надо реверсить клиент, что уж точно плохая затея.

Comment: По-моему очевидно, что проблему нужно решать на сервере, а не на клиенте. Решать проблему со стороны клиента бесполезное и неблагодарное занятие. Пакеты авторизации тоже зашифрованы? Если нет, то их можно ловить и проверять на сервере, если да, то непонятно почему сервер ложится, когда получает неправильно зашифрованный пакет? Если это баг серверного приложения, то может этот баг разработчики уже поправили?

Comment: @Sergeich, а вот о шифрации и вообще о том, что протокол обмена между клиентом и сервером Вам неизвестен, в тексте вопроса ничего нет.

А вообще прокси работает примерно так: на IP, с которым работает клиент вешается программа, которая переправляет данные на другой IP (реальному серверу), который отвечает, конечно же ей, считая что это клиент, а она в свою очередь пересылает данные клиенту.

Понятно, что прокси может изменить данные или вовсе не посылать их. Только, вот, без знания протокола обмена ловить тут нечего.

Comment: > надо реверсить клиент, что уж точно плохая затея.

Это не плохая затея, а единственный возможный путь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Да уж, вариантов, я смотрю, не много ( Я буду думать. Прошу меня извинить, я действительно забыл упомянуть о шифровании. Зашифровано всё подряд. Когда сервер ложится, пакет приходит, судя по моим исследованиям, в точности такой же, как и должен, видимо, логика работы сервера не вполне правильная.

Оставим пока вариант с прокси. А как можно было бы обнаружить перехват пакетов на стороне клиента?

Comment: @Sergeich

    А как можно было бы обнаружить перехват пакетов на стороне клиента?

Скорее всего никак.